# cant load compontents or utilities in tailwind

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

i've installed tailwindcss via npm, created tailwind.config.js created input file for the build, but it builds just the base of tailwind, in the output file.. Does anyone have clue how to fix that? thank you so much. i'have tried updating node, deleting node_modules and lock... :(

[image: the output file]

[image: the styles.css]